# What is the input shape for LSTM from the data?

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm

I have the dataset of users location that needs to predict the next location of the user based on the previous data. I have selected to predict using lstm but stuck to shape the data.

What should be the input shape of the data for lstm?

```
Total number of rows: 53398560
Total number of columns: 4

Columns: User, Timestamp, slot, Location

Users count: 111247
slot : [0-95] Each slot is the 15 mins of the timestamp.
     2014-01-18 00:00:00 ----- 0
     2014-01-18 23:45:00 ----- 95
No of timestamps for each user = 480 (96 slots * 5 days)

Location: Random points for each user
```

What is Xtrain, Ytrain, Xtest, Ytest for the data above.
I need to predict the next location of each user based on the 480 timestamps.

Comment: what have you tried and what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

keras lstm layer input is  a 3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim). From documentation here https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

So in your case it should be [batch_size, 480, 2] (if your only dimensions for the lstm are the 'slot' and 'location' variables.

Comment: How can we divide Xtrain and Ytrain?

Comment: and also Xtest and Ytest